# Accessing minimongo from template helper meteor / mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I am trying to access my Products collection in Minimongo in the html page. When I am in my browser console, I am able to type `Products.findOne();`  and it will return a product.

However, when I try to return a product from my template helper, I get undefined. Thoughts anyone?

```
Template.Tires.onRendered(function() {
 console.log(Products.findOne());
 //after I return a product item, I need to modify its properties manually after it has loaded into the client 

});
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to access the client database (`Products`) before it has received data from the server. When you type the query in your console the collection had all the time to receive whatever it needed to, but if you're immediately executing a query (such as in a helper) before it's ready, then you won't get anything back. Try posting your router/template codes if any, so that we can have some context to work onto.

Comment: Thanks - i posted my template code. If that's the case, is there a way I can delay the query until the data has finished loading?

Comment: with few exceptions, script tags aren't used in meteor. instead, use a helper. I really recommend you learn the basics before getting frustrated https://www.meteor.com/learn

Comment: @MattK is right, you need some learning resources first. As such and without more context as to what you want to achieve (simply logging data, using it in a template, ...) it will be very hard to properly answer. As for your issue, you should take interest in: [Subscriptions](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish), [Collections](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection), [what a reactive variable is](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar), [`Tracker`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker) and [`Template` helpers](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers). Doc grind!

Comment: hi - i have already read and have a suitable understanding of meteor basics. i am coding this in this unorthodox manner to solve a problem relating to a 3rd party package that has internal subscribe/publish functions that I can't override. therefore, i am trying to access and manipulate data after it has reached the client in minimongo... please see my updated question. any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: 
Do whatever modification you need to do on the collection within the helper function and then return a JS object. For instance if you collection looks something like this:

```
SomeColleciton
  _id
    type: String
  birthday:
    type: Date
  firstname:
    type: String
  lastname:
    type: String
  timezone:
    type: Integer
```

you can do the following to transform it

```
Template.Tires.helpers({
  user: function(userId) {
    var u = SomeCollection.findOne(userId);
    var age = calcAge(u.birthday);
    var ifworkinghour = calcifworkinghour(u.timezone);
    return {name: u.firstname + ' ' + u.lastname, age: age, workinghour: ifworkinghour}

});
```

Comment: Thank you. So that will return information for one user. And to call it in the template, I can do {{user('someUserid')}}, correct?

Comment: Yes. Althought to be syntactically correct, {{user someUserId}} is what would work.